# C macro for dot product with variable dimension

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have encountered the following macro construct defining the dot product in the header file of an implementation of a mathematical algorithm.

```
#define DIM 3
#define MULTIPLY( a, b)     ((a)*(b))
#define DOT_PRODUCT( a, b)  (     MULTIPLY( (a)[0],(b)[0]) + \
                                 MULTIPLY( (a)[1],(b)[1]) + \
                                 MULTIPLY( (a)[2],(b)[2]) )
```

It is presumably used to keep the implementation independent of the dimension. But obviously, if one changes `DIM` one must also modify `DOT_PRODUCT` to reflect that.

Is there a way to define `DOT_PRODUCT` so that it respects the set dimension `DIM` automatically? Perhaps with some (pseudo) recursive macro magic? I have tried to come up with something, but my C-foo is not particularly strong.

Comment: I wouldn't think so, but you could use conditional logic to handle all cases for `DIM` in a small range.

Comment: Don't use a macro where a function will do as well.

Comment: You could do it with [Boost::Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/preprocessor/) — even in C; that code is for the C or C++ preprocessor.  You shouldn't do it with Boost::Preprocessor.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Olaf : Do not use macros where functions can be used. 
But sometimes circumstances or desires override that thought.

The preprocessor sometimes just wants the right number of indirections at the right place, so I experimented until I got this. I admit I could not predict and I cannot explain in detail, at least not the interesting, non-obvious parts.

```
#define DIM 2  
#define CONCAT(x,y,a,b) x ## y(a,b)  
#define DOT_PRODUCT_DIM(y,a,b) CONCAT(DOT_PRODUCT_,y,a,b)  
#define MULTIPLY( a, b)     ((a)*(b))  
#define DOT_PRODUCT_2( a, b)  (  MULTIPLY( (a)[0],(b)[0]) + \  
                                 MULTIPLY( (a)[1],(b)[1]) )  
#define DOT_PRODUCT_3( a, b)  (  MULTIPLY( (a)[0],(b)[0]) + \  
                                 MULTIPLY( (a)[1],(b)[1]) + \  
                                 MULTIPLY( (a)[2],(b)[2]) )  
#define DOT_PRODUCT_4( a, b)  (  MULTIPLY( (a)[0],(b)[0]) + \  
                                 MULTIPLY( (a)[1],(b)[1]) + \  
                                 MULTIPLY( (a)[2],(b)[2]) + \  
                                 MULTIPLY( (a)[3],(b)[3]) )  
#define DOT_PRODUCT(a,b)  DOT_PRODUCT_DIM(DIM,a,b)  

DOT_PRODUCT_DIM(2,a,b)  
DOT_PRODUCT_DIM(3,a,b)  
DOT_PRODUCT_DIM(4,a,b)  
DOT_PRODUCT_DIM(DIM,a,b)  
DOT_PRODUCT(a,b)
```

OUTPUT (`gcc -E Toy.c`):

```
( (((a)[0])*((b)[0])) + (((a)[1])*((b)[1])) )
( (((a)[0])*((b)[0])) + (((a)[1])*((b)[1])) + (((a)[2])*((b)[2])) )
( (((a)[0])*((b)[0])) + (((a)[1])*((b)[1])) + (((a)[2])*((b)[2])) + (((a)[3])*((b)[3])) )
( (((a)[0])*((b)[0])) + (((a)[1])*((b)[1])) )
( (((a)[0])*((b)[0])) + (((a)[1])*((b)[1])) )
```

OUTPUT (after only changing `#define DIM 3`, quoting only the last two lines of output):

```
( (((a)[0])*((b)[0])) + (((a)[1])*((b)[1])) + (((a)[2])*((b)[2])) )
( (((a)[0])*((b)[0])) + (((a)[1])*((b)[1])) + (((a)[2])*((b)[2])) )
```

OUTPUT (after only changing `#define DIM 4`, quoting only the last two lines of output):

```
( (((a)[0])*((b)[0])) + (((a)[1])*((b)[1])) + (((a)[2])*((b)[2])) + (((a)[3])*((b)[3])) )
( (((a)[0])*((b)[0])) + (((a)[1])*((b)[1])) + (((a)[2])*((b)[2])) + (((a)[3])*((b)[3])) )
```

OUTPUT (after only changing `#define DIM 5`, quoting only the last two lines of output):

```
DOT_PRODUCT_5(a,b)
DOT_PRODUCT_5(a,b)
```

Of course, the intermediate macros `DOT_PRODUCT_number()` have to be defined. The examples I provided work, so there is no systematic problem, which would prevent higher dimensions.
I hope that matches the use case. Your are not thinking of indeterminate, statically unknown/unpredictable high numbers of dimensions, are you?

Comment: Interesting solution, this would cover my use case. I only really need a variant that allows me to treat 2d and 3d the same by changing DIM.  Of cause an ideal solution would be fully flexible, but this is helpful nevertheless, thank you. Just one question could something similar not be achieved by an IF-ELSEIF-ELSE construct?

Comment: I thought I adressed exactly the need to only switch DIM. What about that does not work for you? My three examples show, that only switching DIM through 2,3,4(,5) gives appropriate results. An IF-ELSEIF construct would be possible, too. But I was (unintentionally and unknowingly) challenged by @John Coleman. His comment sounded like he considered it the only way. Also, my solution gives (in addition to the DIM-controlled default) access to the explicitly dimensioned  `DOT_PRODUCT_digit()` versions. E.g when you mostly do 3dim but have a few cases of 4dim.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment, your solution **does**  work for me as I only need DIM=2 or DIM=3. But in that case IF-ELSE would probably be easier. Initially I was looking for the perfect solution that could handle an arbitrary DIM, but that is more that what I really *need* to solve my problem.

Comment: Do you want an answer based on `#if`?. I would not enjoy it, but if you need me to help I will.

Comment: No, thank you, that I should manage on my own. I primarily asked this question to find out if there is some (more or less obvious) way to make the macro fully dynamic. Apparently that is not the case.